Repair/replace waste pipe
Have this damaged waste pipe. Pipe was so old that when I attempted to remove the P-trap, the pipe simply started disintegrating.


I removed two clamps and the sleeve (Fernco pipe coupler). I tried to twist the damaged pipe and it does not turn. There is some water escaping outside from the bottom. The iron pipe looks rusty but touching it feels solid, it's not crumbling.
I'm thinking about possibilities that don't involve needing to spend money with a plumber:

Remove the chrome pipe (by crushing, twisting)
Install a PVC connector like this:

Seal the PVC and the iron pipe with silicone

Would that be acceptable?
Thank you.

the steel will continue to rust under the silicone.

Honestly, if you can't get the chromed tube out, I think your best bet is simply another Fernco.

saw the chrome pipe neat the grey connector and then pull grey connector away from the wall starting at the back.  pushing the back end away from the wall will cause it to expand. (if this does not work you can cut it off)
once that's off crush the remaining chrome pipe using pliers and twist it out of the iron  pipe. - twisting it will cause it bunch up, and thus to shrink away from the iron pipe.
It looks like the iron pipe may be rusting out and need replacing, I'm not an expert on iron plumbing so I'm going to stop there.
It may be possible to unscrew the iron part and replace it without disassembling the wall, or that may cause other rusty parts to break.
Using silicone caulk to seal plastic to iron is unlikely to work well.

Using a strap/chain wrench around the chrome section may also be sufficient to break it loose.  The rubber Fernco-style connector looks like it should be able to simply slide over the chrome piece (might need a lil lube).

Thanks @Jasen. I've edited the question after I removed the Fernco coupler.

Thanks @Huesmann. I've edited the question after I removed the Fernco coupler.
